# Basic Differential Geometry Problem 1

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

This problem is part of a practice problem set for my exam, and I'm having trouble with it.

A unit sphere $S^{2} = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \ \vert \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$ is rotating  around the $z$ axis making one full turn per unit time. An ant is walking along the meridian with constant speed, making its way from pole to pole at $a$ units of time.

(a) Find the lattitude $\psi(t)$ and the longitude $\phi(t)$ of the ant at time $t$, provided it starts at $t = 0$ from the North Pole (the point $(0,0,1)$).

(b) Find coodrinates $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ of the ant in the ambient 3-space as functions of the time t.

(c) Find the velocity $(\frac{dx}{dt}(s),\frac{dy}{dt}(s),\frac{dz}{dt}(s))$ where the moment of time $s$ is such that $(x(s),y(s),z(s)) = (a,b,c) \in S^2$. Check that the velocity is tangent to the sphere at the point $(a,b,c)$. How to prove the last statement not computing the velocity explicitly?

Comment: Please stop putting several Questio nin one post otherwise all your Question will stay clsoe

Comment: Apologies, it was a multi-part question in my problem set, so I wrote it as it is.

Comment: Rather it will be suit for you to split them in sub-Questions. It need times for people to type and response nicely to full exercise

Comment: Right, of course. My sincere apologies

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of proving the statement, I guess. But the following would be a simple and easy solution for this problem:

Let a point on the sphere be $p(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t))$.
Since the point moves along the sphere, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle p(t), p(t) \rangle = const,
\end{eqnarray}

where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ stands for inner product.
Differentiating it w.r.t $t$ gives

\begin{eqnarray}
2 \langle \frac{d}{dt}p(t), p(t) \rangle = 0,
\end{eqnarray}

which means $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}p(s)$ is perpendicular to p(s).